# removing database hits when accessing foreign field

Tags: database, django, orm

I'm creating a dictionary for my model and use the dictionary to make json data.

```
class MyImage(models.Model):
  ...
  album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
  def to_dict(self):
     result = {}
     result['id'] = self.id
     .. additional data...
     result['album_id'] = self.album.id  // database hit
     result['album_title'] = self.album.title  // another database hit
     result['album_something'] = self.album.something // another hit
```

I just found out that to create a dictionary of MyImage I need 1+3 as noted in the comment above.

Can I cut down the DB hit to 1+1 instead of 1+3 somehow?

Comment: can you not do `album=self.album` and `album.id`, `album.title` would serve the results from the cache.

Comment: @karthikr: I tried it, it's hitting DB the same # of times.

Comment: i tried similar code, after album being accessed first time, there's no more db hits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use select_related.

From the Docs

Returns a QuerySet that will automatically "follow" foreign-key relationships, selecting that additional related-object data when it executes its query. This is a performance booster which results in (sometimes much) larger queries but means later use of foreign-key relationships won't require database queries.

```
# Hits the database.
e = Entry.objects.get(id=5)

# Hits the database again to get the related Blog object.
b = e.blog

# Hits the database.
e = Entry.objects.select_related().get(id=5)

# Doesn't hit the database, because e.blog has been prepopulated
# in the previous query.
b = e.blog
```

Comment: Yes this works. I would have to add select_related() to most of my query.  Still curious though `can you not do album=self.album and album.id, album.title would serve the results from the cache. – karthikr`. Isn't there a way to do this?

Comment: looks like django 1.5 will support the preloading.

Answer (score 0):

you can manage with 1 hit
capture the data to a Value Object (simple class wich has all the database entity attributes) - 1 hit

and serve/construct your json data from the Value Object.

Comment: I don't fully understand. Can you elaborate?

Comment: have one query / db method to extract all the values from db. and cache / store them to a Class.

Comment: have one query / db method to extract all the values from db. and cache / store them to a Class. and then use the fields as an when requiered instead of going to the db for every field. makes sense ?

Comment: Yes I understand the concept, but how? use raw sql?

Comment: use [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615357/django-querysets-memcached-best-practices) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631865/caching-query-results-in-django)