# Wierd caching behaviour in django

Tags: django, caching, django-queryset, tastypie, django-cache

I am using django's local memory cache (`django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache`) and using `tastypie` for REST API.

I have following code in `CommentResource` object in file `api.py`:

```
def get_object_list(self, request):
    cached_comments = cache.get('comments')
    if cached_comments is not None:
        print 'got comments in cache'
        return cached_comments
    print "didn't get comments in cache"
    comments = super(CommentResource, self).get_object_list(request).order_by('-created')
    cache.set('comments', comments, 100)
    return comments
```

Now when I save a new comment, the API returns the new comment too, even though it prints `got comments in cache`. How can the new comment possibly be cached?
There must be something wrong. Could the tastypie's `dehydrate` method be an issue here?

UPDATE: I commented out the `dehydrate` method and still the same issue. So that might not be the problem.

UPDATE 2: Even though, django's `querysets` are lazy, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615357/django-querysets-memcached-best-practices) says that

> Querysets are lazy, which means they don't call the database until
>   they're evaluated. One way they could get evaluated would be to
>   serialize them, which is what cache.set does behind the scenes.

So laziness of `querysets` doesn't explain this behaviour.

Comment: How are you outputting the comments? Are you slicing them, or paginating?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Tastypie has pagination by default. That's what I am using.